# Why are the chunks in Mongodb collections are not balanced?

Tags: mongodb

There are few sharded collections across few databases in my MongoDB cluster and data ingestion was going at high speed. I noticed that with time one of the shards started getting more and more chunks. There are four shards in the cluster. One of the shard was getting almost 2150 chunks, while others were at around 750 chunks each. As a result, the one with higher number of chunks was getting much more writes and was at very high CPU.  What may lead to such situation and what is the mitigation ?  The chunks were having roughly equal number of documents and everything looked fine.

Also, when I stopped data ingestion, I noticed the shards were slowly getting balanced in terms of the number of chunks.

Comment: Your chunks *are* being balanced according to your question, so what are you asking exactly?

Comment: @D.SM the problem is, balancing seems really slow and while ingestion was on, the imbalance was growing leading to very uneven CPU usages among the shards. This is really a problem. I stopped ingestion in between to check if balaner can eventually make the shard balanced.

Comment: Are shard key values evenly distributed in the value space? Try a hashed shard key.

Comment: Yes. Shard keys are evenly distributed. And I checked the chunks are good to and there was no reason for the chunks for one collection to get allocated more to one shard.

Comment: Add an mcve demonstrating the behavior you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB should evenly distribute documents across shards when the documents have uniform distribution of shard key values. [Test with hashed shard keys](https://github.com/p-mongo/tests/tree/master/shard-dist) which is one way to obtain such a distribution.